# ActionScript 3 class over several files - how?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

So, how do we write a class over several files in action script 3?

In C# there's the "partial" keyword.

In C++ it's natural (you just "#include ..." all files).

In Flex 3, in a component, you add this tag: `<mx:Script source="myfile.as"/>`.

How do I split the following class into several files;

```
package package_path
{
    public class cSplitMeClass
    {
        public function cSplitMeClass()
        {
        }

        public function doX():void
        {
            // ....
        }

        public function doY():void
        {
            // ....
        }
    }
}
```

For example I want to have the doX() and doY() functions implemented in another ".as" file.

Can I do this?

And please, don't tell me something like "a good practice is to have them in one file" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per your request, I'm sparing you the "best practices lecture". So, I'll just say there's an [include directive](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/statements.html#include) in AS 3.0, which could help you out here.

Basically, you can do:

```
package package_path
{
    public class cSplitMeClass
    {
        public function cSplitMeClass()
        {
        }

        include "the_file_where_doX_and_doY_live.as"
     }
}
```

And then in "the_file_where_doX_and_doY_live.as"

```
    public function doX():void
    {
        // ....
    }

    public function doY():void
    {
        // ....
    }
```

Comment: Yup, that's it! So simple, yet so "complicated" to find. Typical Adobe's cryptographic.. (: Thank you!

Comment: Nifty. If you do this, how do you retain references to movie clips on the main stage with code from the "the_file_where_doX_and_doY_live.as" file?

Comment: @Gregir the include copies the code from "the_file_where_doX_and_doY_live.as" to cSplitMeClass, so you access everything you need the same way whether your code is in an included file or in the main file.

Comment: Weird. As I type code into my "the_file_where_doX_and_doY_live.as" file, Flash Builder gives me errors saying the instance names for the clips on the stage are undefined.

Comment: Mmm, I haven't checked it but my guess is that it's an IDE issue (buggy support for include). Again, I'm guessing, but probably it compiles (don't know if it does with FB, it should with MXMLC, the compiler that FB uses)

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I see you have to put the include statement precisely where you'd need that code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with inheritance:

```
// file: cSplitMe1.as

class cSplitMe1 {

   function doX() {
       // ...
   }

// file: cSplitMe2.as

class cSplitMe2 extends cSplitMe1 {

   function doY() {
       // ...
   }

// file: cSplitMe.as

class cSplitMe extends cSplitMe2 {

   function cSplitMe() {
       doX();
       doY();
   }
}
```

Comment: This is actually best practices if you divide up the classes in a way that makes sense. Flex frameworks does that for example. Now if you are just doing it because you want to dump a ton of code into a single class, and you split it in ways that don't make sense...well that's bad.

Answer (score -1):

It's good practice, nothing wrong with that.

There's the `import` keyword. Example:

```
import Class_A.as;
import Class_B.as;
```

Now of course in order to use them, you need to declare them, preferably in your constructor.

```
public function Class_C()
{
    //Create a new instance of Class_A
    var objA:Object = new Class_A("parameter one", "parameter two");
    //Create a new instance of Class_B
    var objA:Object = new Class_B("parameter one", "parameter two");
}
```

Of course it all depends on how you're going to make this work. I would also suggest you use a Main class from where you could run your code. I guess you already knew that though.

Good luck.

Comment: Not understood. I'm not sure you understood what I was asking. I know how to "import" other classes. I don't know, and want to know, how I can write one class over several ".as" files!